# Call APNDroid from my app

Tags: android, 3g

I am trying to write an app that calls APNDroid for enabling/disabling the 3G.
I looked at the code snippets provided by the developer.
I can't seem to understand how to incorporate them in my code.
Here is the code snippet I am referring to:

```
boolean targetState = getCheckBoxState(R.id.target_state);
boolean keepMms = getCheckBoxState(R.id.keep_mms);
boolean showNotification = getCheckBoxState(R.id.show_notification);
Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationConstants.CHANGE_STATUS_REQUEST);
int onState = ApplicationConstants.State.ON;
int offState = ApplicationConstants.State.OFF;  
intent.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.TARGET_MMS_STATE, keepMms ? onState : offState); 
intent.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.TARGET_APN_STATE, targetState ? onState : offState); 
intent.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.SHOW_NOTIFICATION, showNotification); 
MyActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, CHANGE_REQUEST);
```

Specifically, I do not understand how this code knows to call an APNDroid activity.
The constants are found [here](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/source/browse/src/com/google/code/apndroid/Constants.java)

Obviously none of this is recognized by "eclipse" when I embed it in my code.
Should I import something? 
Should I somehow give a reference to the APNDroid app?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.
Avi

Answer (score 0):

You first have to checkout the project. Following these [steps](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/)

You also have in that piece of code the name of the Intent to call. Have a look here to see how to call the intent of another applications in Android
[Call or start external Application Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716745/call-or-start-external-application-android)